# remove duplicate coumn of only one column have all value from all the available from duplicate columns in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel

Imported  Excel sheet  To SQL server.i have selects one table . in this table have  lot of  Rows values. in this Rows single Employee comes in this Table  many time. i want single Employee in this COlumn should  have  all values available  from Repeated columns. i will show  Sample Data for reference.

```
    Name    E1   E2 E3  E4  E5
    Jeni    1    0  0   0   0
    Jeni    0    0  2   0   0
    Jeni    0    5  0   0   3
    Priya   0    3  0   0   0
    Priya   0    0  0   0   3
    Priya   0    0  7   0   0
    Priya   10   0  0   0   0
```

My table Looks like after Select the Table my Result should be Like

```
 Name  E1  E2   E3  E4   E5  Total 
 jeni   1  5    2    0    3    11
 Priya  10 3    7    0    3    23
```

i want be like this. i hope Explained  little bit clear.please how can achieve this. please also Refer BEST TUTORIAL For learn SQL  very short period .thank you  advance .  I hope some Wil help. I am new SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([Name] varchar(5), [E1] int, [E2] int, [E3] int, [E4] int, [E5] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([Name], [E1], [E2], [E3], [E4], [E5])
VALUES
    ('Jeni', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    ('Jeni', 0, 0, 2, 0, 0),
    ('Jeni', 0, 5, 0, 0, 3),
    ('Priya', 0, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    ('Priya', 0, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    ('Priya', 0, 0, 7, 0, 0),
    ('Priya', 10, 0, 0, 0, 0)
;

SELECT *,A.E1+A.E2+A.E3+A.E4+A.E5 AS 'TOTAL' FROM ( SELECT NAME, SUM(E1) E1 ,SUM(E2) E2 ,SUM(E3) E3 ,SUM(E4) E4 ,SUM(E5) E5 FROM #TABLE1 GROUP BY NAME)A
```

output

```
NAME    E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  TOTAL
Jeni    1   5   2   0   3   11
Priya   10  3   7   0   3   23
```

Comment: You might want to use `SUM()` instead of `MAX()`, in case the non-zero values could be negative +1

Comment: @Chanukya one More Help. i want calculate Total value   separate Employee Total Like jeni    Total 11 and Priya 23.  i am updated my Question please give some Idea  how to get value

Comment: @sripriya check answer now

Answer (score 3):

The thing you are looking for is a Group by .

To get the result you are looking for , i just made the table you described and did a group by and did a sum on the integer values.

```
select name, sum(E1),sum(E2),sum(E3),sum(E4),sum(E5) from Test Group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte(Name,E1,E2,E3,E4,E5)
AS
(
SELECT 'Jeni' ,1 ,0 , 0, 0, 0 Union all
SELECT 'Jeni' ,0 ,0 , 2, 0, 0 Union all
SELECT 'Jeni' ,0 ,5 , 0, 0, 3 Union all
SELECT 'Priya',0 ,3 , 0, 0, 0 Union all
SELECT 'Priya',0 ,0 , 0, 0, 3 Union all
SELECT 'Priya',0 ,0 , 7, 0, 0 Union all
SELECT 'Priya',10,0 , 0, 0, 0 
)
SELECT Name,E1,E2,E3,E4,E5,Total FROM
(
SELECT *,Row_number()Over(Partition by Name order by Name)AS Seq From
(
SELECT  Name,SUM(E1)E1,
SUM(E2)E2,
SUM(E3)E3,
SUM(E4)E4,
SUM(E5)E5,
SUM(E1+E2+ E3+ E4+E5) AS Total
FROM cte
Group by Name
)Dt
)AS Final
WHERE Final.Seq=1
```